# how to delete items in listview? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i populate items in `listview` and when i click the command button i will add the item in the list in the database and if an item from the list hasn't been checked out it will delete the item from the populated list below is my code.

```
Dim y As Integer
Dim a As String
y = ListView2.Items.Count
While y >= 0
    a = ListView2.Items.Item(y).Text
    y = y - 1

    Dim TMP_SQL_VAL As String = "select count([Check-Out]) from tbl_list1 where barcode = '" + a + "'"
    locconn.Open()
    command = New SqlCommand(TMP_SQL_VAL, locconn)
    Dim READER As SqlDataReader
    READER = command.ExecuteReader()
    READER.Read()

    If READER(0) = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Barcode: " & a & "is still Inside", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        clear_text()

        ListView2.Items.Remove(y)
    Else
        READER.Close()
        Dim READER2 As SqlDataReader
        Dim TMP_SQL_VAL2 = "select [Check-In] from tbl_list1 where barcode = '" + a + "' and  [User] = '" + rsuser + "'"
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(TMP_SQL_VAL2, locconn)
        READER2 = cmd.ExecuteReader
        READER2.Read()
        If READER2(0) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Barcode: " & a & "is still Inside", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            clear_text()
        ListView2.Items.Remove(y)
        End If
   end if
   locconn.Close()
End While

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    localconn.ShowDialog()
Finally
    locconn.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/170900/How-to-Delete-Selected-Items-of-ListView-and-ListB use this link...

Comment: You should be using RemoveAt instead of Remove in that case because you're using y as index.

RemoveAt removes the item at the specified index.

Remove removes the item itself, which you need to use some sort of For each to loop all the items in the listview to obtain the ListViewItem itself.

I was just trying to help, there's just much as this can be answered, i think.

Comment: but i keep getting error "InvalidArguments=value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name index"

Comment: You have to subtract 1 on y like:
y = Listview1.Items.Count -1

Comment: Because vb.net uses zero-based index, sorry i couldn't edit my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to check if the value of y is < 0, if it is then nothing to process terminate it**

```
Dim y As Integer
Dim a As String
y = ListView2.Items.Count - 1 'Reduce 1
If y < 0 Then return 'If no item then terminate
While y >= 0
    a = ListView2.Items.Item(y).Text
    'y = y - 1    'Moved to last line before End While
    Dim TMP_SQL_VAL As String = "select count([Check-Out]) from tbl_list1 where barcode = '" + a + "'"
    locconn.Open()
    command = New SqlCommand(TMP_SQL_VAL, locconn)
    Dim READER As SqlDataReader
    READER = command.ExecuteReader()
    READER.Read()

    If READER(0) = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Barcode: " & a & "is still Inside", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        clear_text()

        ListView2.Items.Remove(y)
    Else
        READER.Close()
        Dim READER2 As SqlDataReader
        Dim TMP_SQL_VAL2 = "select [Check-In] from tbl_list1 where barcode = '" + a + "' and  [User] = '" + rsuser + "'"
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(TMP_SQL_VAL2, locconn)
        READER2 = cmd.ExecuteReader
        READER2.Read()
        If READER2(0) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Barcode: " & a & "is still Inside", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            clear_text()
        ListView2.Items.Remove(y)
        End If
   end if
   locconn.Close()

   y -= 1  'Move here so the value is decremented before the While statement

End While

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    localconn.ShowDialog()
Finally
    locconn.Close()
End Try
```